# Subsonic and the VB.net 2005 interop toolkit

Tags: vb.net, subsonic, vb6-migration

I have an application I am converting over from vb6 to vb.net 2.0/3.5. Using Subsonic 2.2 and the vb.net Interop Toolkit 2005. Cannot seem to get the .net form using subsonic to work inside the interop environment. It keeps saying it cannot find the subsonic service provider in the app.config. But I know it is there. Has anyone used these two toolkits together successfully? Will subsonic even work inside the interop environment in that way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The provider needs to be declared in whatever primary configuration file is being used by application (may not be web.config). Also, it may help to make SubSonicService the first element in configSections.

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="SubSonicService" type="SubSonic.SubSonicSection, SubSonic" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" restartOnExternalChanges="true" requirePermission="false"/>
    </configSections>
<!--Other stuff-->
</configuration>
```